# Google Maps API not showing up in MVC5

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I followed [this tutorial](http://dotnetdevtricks.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/google-map-api-v3-with-mvc4-razor.html) for creating a Google maps API in my ASP.NET MVC5 project.

I have added this code to my `_Layout.cshtml` (at the bottom, underneath the `<html>` section - have tried moving them to the `<head>` section as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108910/google-map-api-not-showing-up#comment39110214_25111803) but it didn't make any difference):

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
   $(document).ready(function () {  
     initialize();  
   });  
   function initialize() {  
     var mapOptions = {  
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.9167, 79.8473),  
       zoom: 10,  
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  
     };  
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),  
       mapOptions);  
     // create a marker  
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(6.9167, 79.8473);  
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
       position: latlng,  
       map: map,  
       title: 'My Place'  
     });  
   }  
</script>
```

and this code to my view (in the place I want the map to show):

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;">  
</div>
```

At the bottom of my _Layout `<body>` section, I have:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

and in my registering bundles function (which I know is working because rendering other bundles elsewhere is working) I have:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

but it's not working. What I get is a blank space like this (click for bigger version if needed):

[image: broken-map-smaller]

but no map.

I have viewed the page source and both sections of code appear in it. I don't know what else to look at or try, if maybe there's some crucial step that I'm missing, if I need to do something different for MVC5 (the tutorial was for MVC4), if the Google API has changed again and you need a key again to be able to use it, or if the problem is something else entirely.

**Update:** The code above is working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uL2Lshu6/1/) (thanks HoangHieu for getting me started with JSFiddle), so the problem is definitely in the setting up or linking together, not with the JavaScript/JQuery itself.

Comment: **$(document).ready(function () {  
     initialize();  
});**
Change it to **window.onload = initialize;**

Comment: @HoangHieu Done. That didn't change anything. What was the rationale?

Comment: what does mean??? after your change map couldn't show?? or show ???

Comment: @HoangHieu I mean that after the change, the behaviour was exactly as described above (no map, big white space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
```

as given in the tutorial I was following, and several other online tutorials, is incorrect. Perhaps Google Maps has been updated since they were written. In any case, the `src` attribute should use a **https** URL, not http.

I simply changed it to

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
```

and everything worked.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) is some documentation from Google which may help future readers:

> ## HTTPS or HTTP
>
> We think security on the web is pretty important, and recommend using HTTPS whenever possible. As part of our efforts to make the web more secure, we've made all of the Google Maps APIs available over HTTPS. Using HTTPS encryption makes your site more secure, and more resistant to snooping or tampering.
>
> `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"
>     type="text/javascript"></script>`
>
> If required, you can load the Google Maps JavaScript API over HTTP by requesting http://maps.googleapis.com/, or http://maps.google.cn for users in China.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uL2Lshu6/

**Update DEMO**: DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uL2Lshu6/2/

> if You wanna use **$(document)**, you must include **"jQuery"** into
>   html code
>   Have you include **jQuery**

I have change

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
     initialize();  
   });
```

to

```
window.onload = initialize;
```

and it worked. I think it's **differences between JavaScript's window.onload and JQuery's $(document).ready()**

More: [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

The ready event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while the onload event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded.

The onload event is a standard event in the DOM, while the ready event is specific to jQuery. The purpose of the ready event is that it should occur as early as possible after the document has loaded, so that code that adds functionality to the elements in the page doesn't have to wait for all content to load.

> His had been change **http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false**
>   to https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false
>   And it fixed..

Comment: That would make sense if my problem was that the map was taking a long time to load. But the thing is that it just doesn't show up at all. I learned something new about the difference between those two functions, so thanks for taking the time to write an answer, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem I was having.

Comment: Also if I change `window.onload = initialize;` back to `$(document).ready(function () {  
     initialize();  
   });` in your fiddle and click run, [it still displays a map](http://jsfiddle.net/uL2Lshu6/1/), meaning that this line can't be the problem. (It also means that the problem isn't in the scripting itself, but somewhere in the way I've tied everything together or a setting somewhere or something - thanks for helping me to narrow that down.)

Comment: Check my update URL **DEMO**, and you can't use $(document).ready

Comment: I don't see any change between "DEMO" and "UPDATE DEMO"?

Comment: [Revision 5](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29373197/revisions) shows the update to my question. I have a JQuery bundle that includes the JQuery `.js` file and the bundle is rendered at the bottom of _Layout.cshtml. Is this sufficient to include JQuery?

Comment: Oh, Update demo doesn't include **Jquery Library** and you can't use $(document).readY(function(){});

Comment: I appreciate that English isn't your first language, but I've told you *several times now* that **using window.onload = initialize; does not fix the problem**. I appreciate any help you can give, but please don't keep suggesting the same thing over and over when it's already been ruled out. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74359/discussion-between-hoanghieu-and-starsplusplus).

Comment: I'd recommend `src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"`